# How to read kmz stream to parse kml on Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, kml, kmz

I want to convert a kmz stream to a kml stream to parse it.

I tried this to do that with SharpZipLib because I read that kmz is just an zipfile of the kml.

My code :

```
ZipInputStream zipInputStream = new ZipInputStream(myKmzStream);
ZipEntry zipEntry = zipInputStream.GetNextEntry();
// here, zipEntry as a name "doc.kml"
//but zipEntry.ExtraData is null...

byte[] kmlContent = zipEntry.ExtraData; // null
```

Is there any reason I get this result ?
Thanx for help :)

Answer (score -1):

My opinion is that ExtraData is not set (that why the null value). You need to extract the data from the ZIP (KMZ) file out to a stream to parse it further.
Take a look at this sample:
https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib/wiki/Zip-Samples#-unpack-a-zip-with-full-control-over-the-operation

Hope it helps!

Cheers,